# Google Action sends response as "Sorry Something went wrong. Please try again later." in the Transaction flow

Tags: actions-on-google

I am using the orders version 2 APIs of Physical transaction using Google Pay and using Stripe as the payment gateway.

While testing the app using Stripe test publishable I am able to make transactions successfully but when I use the Stripe Live publishable key to generate the chargeable token from Google, the assistant replies with "Something went wrong. Please try again later.". This is happening when I make the conv.ask(new TransactionDecision({})) call.

I get the same response using either of the keys when I disable the Sandbox in the action console simulator.

This response has no error attached with it so I am unable to figure out the cause.

Here is the code-

```
    conv.ask(new TransactionDecision({
                        orderOptions: {
                            requestDeliveryAddress: false,
                        },
                        paymentOptions: {
                            googleProvidedOptions: {
                                prepaidCardDisallowed: false,
                                supportedCardNetworks: ['VISA', 'AMEX', 'MASTERCARD'],
                                tokenizationParameters: {
                                    // Tokenization parameter data  will be provided by
                                    // a payment processor, like Stripe, Braintree, Vantiv, etc.
                                    parameters: {
                                        'gateway': 'stripe',
                                        'stripe:version': '2019-05-16',
                                        'stripe:publishableKey': process.env.CS_ENV === 'prod' ? process.env.STRIPE_LIVE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY : process.env.STRIPE_TEST_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
                                    },
                                    tokenizationType: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        proposedOrder: order,
                    }));
```